# Windows GetDIBits not returning expected values

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, screenshot, pixel

I'm currently writing a small program that scans the screen and looks for pixels. My issue is that GetDIBits function doesn't appear to return a proper screenshot of the screen.

Copying the bitmap to the clipboard does put the right screen image in the clipboard. 
I decided to print out the function's output to a BMP file to get an idea of what's going on and it clearly isn't what I'm expecting.

I'll also mention that I have 3 monitors, incase that could explain why it's not behaving like expected.

```
class Test {
    int screenWidth;
    int screenHeight;
    HWND targetWindow;
    HDC targetDC;
    HDC captureDC;
    RGBQUAD *pixels;
    HBITMAP captureBitmap;


    bool TakeScreenshot() {
        ZeroMemory(pixels, screenHeight*screenWidth);
        screenWidth = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);
        screenHeight = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);

        targetWindow = GetDesktopWindow();
        targetDC = GetDC(NULL);


        captureDC = CreateCompatibleDC(targetDC);

        captureBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(targetDC, screenWidth, screenHeight);
        HGDIOBJ old = SelectObject(captureDC, captureBitmap);
        if (!old)
            printf("Error selecting object\n");

        OpenClipboard(NULL);
        EmptyClipboard();
        SetClipboardData(CF_BITMAP, captureBitmap);
        CloseClipboard();

        if (BitBlt(captureDC, 0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight, targetDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY)) {
            BITMAPINFO bmi = { 0 };
            bmi.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
            bmi.bmiHeader.biWidth = screenWidth;
            bmi.bmiHeader.biHeight = -screenHeight;
            bmi.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
            bmi.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 32;
            bmi.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;
            bmi.bmiHeader.biSizeImage = 0;

            if (!SelectObject(captureDC, old))
                printf("Error unselecting object\n");
            if (!GetDIBits(captureDC,
                captureBitmap,
                0,
                screenHeight,
                pixels,
                &bmi,
                DIB_RGB_COLORS
            )) {
                printf("%s: GetDIBits failed\n", __FUNCTION__);
                return false;
            }

        }
        else {
            printf("%s: BitBlt failed\n", __FUNCTION__);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    // This is from somewhere on stackoverflow - can't find where.
    void MakePicture() {
        typedef struct                       /**** BMP file header structure ****/
        {
            unsigned int   bfSize;           /* Size of file */
            unsigned short bfReserved1;      /* Reserved */
            unsigned short bfReserved2;      /* ... */
            unsigned int   bfOffBits;        /* Offset to bitmap data */
        } BITMAPFILEHEADER;

        BITMAPFILEHEADER bfh;
        BITMAPINFOHEADER bih;

        unsigned short bfType = 0x4d42;
        bfh.bfReserved1 = 0;
        bfh.bfReserved2 = 0;
        bfh.bfSize = 2 + sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER) + 2560 * 1440 * 3;
        bfh.bfOffBits = 0x36;

        bih.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
        bih.biWidth = screenWidth;
        bih.biHeight = screenHeight;
        bih.biPlanes = 1;
        bih.biBitCount = 24;
        bih.biCompression = 0;
        bih.biSizeImage = 0;
        bih.biXPelsPerMeter = 5000;
        bih.biYPelsPerMeter = 5000;
        bih.biClrUsed = 0;
        bih.biClrImportant = 0;

        FILE *file;
        fopen_s(&file, "test.bmp", "wb");
        if (!file)
        {
            printf("Could not write file\n");
            return;
        }

        /*Write headers*/
        fwrite(&bfType, 1, sizeof(bfType), file);
        fwrite(&bfh, 1, sizeof(bfh), file);
        fwrite(&bih, 1, sizeof(bih), file);

        /*Write bitmap*/
        for (int y = 0; y < screenHeight; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < screenWidth; x++)
            {
                unsigned char r = pixels[x + y].rgbRed;
                unsigned char g = pixels[x + y].rgbGreen;
                unsigned char b = pixels[x + y].rgbBlue;
                fwrite(&b, 1, 1, file);
                fwrite(&g, 1, 1, file);
                fwrite(&r, 1, 1, file);
            }
        }
        fclose(file);
    }
    Test() {
        screenWidth = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);
        screenHeight = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);
        pixels = new RGBQUAD[screenWidth * screenHeight];
    }
    ~Test() {
        //cleanup
    }
};
```

Here is the result that the code is giving(instead of a screenshot):
[image]

It appears like it takes a few pixels from the top of my screen and stretches them into an image. The screenshot is from Visual Studio being open(orange part being the notifications).

If I put a giant red square (255, 0, 0) in my screen, if it's height isn't 0, the pixels array will not contain a single red pixel.

Comment: You're not initializing `screenWidth` and other globals.  Edit your question to include a [mcve].

Comment: At the time you put `captureBitmap` in the clipboard (1) you haven't yet captured the bitmap and (2) you no longer own that bitmap handle -- the system does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BitBlt` performs the actual copying. Clipboard functions should be called after `BitBlt`

Also note, in mutli-monitor settings, `SM_CXSCREEN/Y...` give the size for the primary monitor. Use `SM_XVIRTUALSCREEN/XV...` for the whole screen. `SM_XVIRTUALSCREEN/Y` will give the X/Y coordinate (it's usually zero)

Be sure to release all the handles and delete the used objects when you are finished. In fact, there is no need to declare `targetDC` etc. as class members.

If the application is not DPI aware, the bitmap may look smaller depending on DPI settings. Call `SetProcessDPIAware()` at the start of the program for a quick fix, or set the manifest.

As noted in comment, with `SetClipboardData(CF_BITMAP, captureBitmap);` the system takes over `captureBitmap`. Avoid calling this function or make a copy of the bitmap to pass to clipboard.

```
int main()
{
    int screenWidth = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXVIRTUALSCREEN);
    int screenHeight = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYVIRTUALSCREEN);
    int screen_x = GetSystemMetrics(SM_XVIRTUALSCREEN);
    int screen_y = GetSystemMetrics(SM_YVIRTUALSCREEN);

    screenWidth = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);
    screenHeight = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);
    screen_x = 0;
    screen_y = 0;

    RGBQUAD* pixels = new RGBQUAD[screenWidth * screenHeight];

    DWORD size = screenWidth * screenHeight * 4;

    ZeroMemory(pixels, size);

    HDC targetDC = GetDC(NULL);
    HDC captureDC = CreateCompatibleDC(targetDC);
    HBITMAP captureBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(targetDC, screenWidth, screenHeight);
    HGDIOBJ old = SelectObject(captureDC, captureBitmap);

    if(!BitBlt(captureDC, 0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight, targetDC,
        screen_x, screen_y, SRCCOPY))
        printf("BitBlt error\n");

    SelectObject(captureDC, old);

    BITMAPINFO bmi = { 0 };
    bmi.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
    bmi.bmiHeader.biWidth = screenWidth;
    bmi.bmiHeader.biHeight = -screenHeight;
    bmi.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
    bmi.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 32;
    bmi.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;
    bmi.bmiHeader.biSizeImage = 0;

    if(OpenClipboard(NULL))
    {
        EmptyClipboard();
        SetClipboardData(CF_BITMAP, 
                    CopyImage(captureBitmap, IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_DEFAULTSIZE));
        CloseClipboard();
    }

    if(!GetDIBits(targetDC,
        captureBitmap,
        0,
        screenHeight,
        pixels,
        &bmi,
        DIB_RGB_COLORS
    ))
        printf("%s: GetDIBits failed\n", __FUNCTION__);

    BITMAPFILEHEADER filehdr = { 'MB', 54 + size, 0, 0, 54 };
    std::ofstream f("test.bmp", std::ios::binary);
    f.write((char*)&filehdr, sizeof(filehdr));
    f.write((char*)&bmi, sizeof(bmi));
    f.write((char*)pixels, size);

    //cleanup:      
    SelectObject(captureDC, old);
    DeleteObject(captureBitmap);
    DeleteDC(captureDC);
    ReleaseDC(0, targetDC);
}
```

Comment: The 'pixels' array still seems to result in the picture above.

Comment: I added it to the post. I've also tried printing the color at a specific coordinate (x,y)  in the console and it results in the same color that is on the image.

The only colors in that array appears to be from the first line of pixel on my screen.

Comment: You are reading the file in 32-bit format, the pixels are 32-bit, then you write in 24-bit. See update on saving the bitmap in 32-bit format. Or change the pixels to 24-bit and save in 24-bit.

Comment: Lots of good info here, but this still has the problem that once you give the bitmap to the clipboard, it's not yours anymore.  You cannot reliably read from it with GetDIBits.  If you eliminate the calls to the clipboard in this code (or in the OP), you get the expected data in `pixels`.

Comment: Good point @AdrianMcCarthy. But does that makes a difference in this case? because `GetDIBits` doesn't attempt to modify the bitmap. I added `CopyImage` to avoid the problem.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani:  From documentation for SetClipboardData: "If SetClipboardData succeeds, the system owns the object identified by the hMem parameter. The application may not write to or free the data once ownership has been transferred to the system, but it can lock and read from the data until the CloseClipboard function is called."  Since CloseClipboard has been called, you cannot even be sure the data is still there.  Also, the code works for me if omit the clipboard operations.

Answer (score 1):

[GetDIBits function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-getdibits) reference, remarks section:

> The bitmap identified by the hbmp parameter must not be selected into
>   a device context when the application calls this function.

Deselect bitmap before calling `GetBIBits`.

```
HBITMAP oldBitmap = SelectObject(captureDC, captureBitmap);
...
// Deselect captureBitmap by selecting oldBitmap.
SelectObject(captureDC, oldBitmap);
```

Remember to add cleanup code (restore bitmap, destroy bitmap, destroy or release device contexts).

Comment: It still gives me bad results. It seems to take a few pixels from the top of my screen and put them in a weird way. (The image I provided is the one resulting from visual studio being open, orange bit is the notification flag that shows up in the top bar)

Answer (score 1):

Additional bug:

```
    for (int y = 0; y < screenHeight; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < screenWidth; x++)
        {
            unsigned char r = pixels[x + y].rgbRed;
            unsigned char g = pixels[x + y].rgbGreen;
            unsigned char b = pixels[x + y].rgbBlue;
            fwrite(&b, 1, 1, file);
            fwrite(&g, 1, 1, file);
            fwrite(&r, 1, 1, file);
        }
    }
```

I think it should be

```
    for (int y = 0; y < screenHeight; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < screenWidth; x++)
        {
            unsigned char r = pixels[x + y*screenWidth].rgbRed;
            unsigned char g = pixels[x + y*screenWidth].rgbGreen;
            unsigned char b = pixels[x + y*screenWidth].rgbBlue;
            fwrite(&b, 1, 1, file);
            fwrite(&g, 1, 1, file);
            fwrite(&r, 1, 1, file);
        }
    }
```

But rows require padding to multiplies of 4 bytes:

```
    // Important: each row has to be padded to multiple of DWORD.
    // Valid only for 24 bits per pixel bitmaps.
    // Remark: 32 bits per pixel have rows always aligned (padding==0)
    int padding = 3 - (screenWidth*3 + 3)%4;
    // or
    // int padding = 3 - ((screenWidth*3 + 3) & 3);
    for (int y = 0; y < screenHeight; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < screenWidth; x++)
        {
            unsigned char r = pixels[x + y*screenWidth].rgbRed;
            unsigned char g = pixels[x + y*screenWidth].rgbGreen;
            unsigned char b = pixels[x + y*screenWidth].rgbBlue;
            fwrite(&b, 1, 1, file);
            fwrite(&g, 1, 1, file);
            fwrite(&r, 1, 1, file);
        }
        // Important: each row has to be padded to multiple of DWORD.
        fwrite("\0\0\0\0", 1, padding, file);
    }
```

Adjust file size (valid for 24 bits per pixel):

```
    bfh.bfSize =
            2
            + sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER)
            + sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER)
            + ((screenWidth*3 + 3) & ~3) * screenHeight;
```